# FAB from design library - wrong position

Tags: android, android-design-library, floating-action-button

Recently I had been trying to use new Design library from Google but FAB View did not work as I would expect.

Here's what my layout looks like (I removed children of those layouts in CoordinatorLayout to make it clearer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_clear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/material_54"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_rewrite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/material_54"/>

    <include layout="@layout/shadow_down" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/window_background"/>

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_import"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/log_cell_changed"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_16"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_16"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that FAB is not present on the screen when I run the app. However "preview" on Android Studio shows it correctly.
I tried to play with it a bit and when I add

`android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"`

to FAB it will cause that the FAB will appear just where it should be placed without that additional margin.

[image: Result of preview in Android Studio]
[image: Real result when I run the app]

Comment: witch version of Design Library you are using? i created a sample project with your code and everything works fine. i'm using `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`

Comment: I'm also using 23.0.1 (Android 6.0, Nexus 5, Developer preview 3)

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_alignParentBottom and layout_alignParentRight as true like in the below example

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fac_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
            android:src="@mipmap/fab_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_color"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white" />
```